# Is marvel and dc in the same endo/multiverse, or at least “travel-able”?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, dc-extended-universe

I know the story about Buried Alien (aka Barry Allen (probably))  but that was not like this.

I found on on another post that deadstroke - from dc - slade wilson has the same surname as deadpool(wade wilson)?They both use guns and that stuff.
I also found out that superman battled spiderman (but that was because that happened before they came up with a multiverse) but then I found this picture.
[image: the Flash batteling Quicksilver]
This is Flash batteling Quicksilver. I dont know where its from, but how could they ever meet, since Quicksilver is from marvel?
And why can wade wilson and slade wilson have the same surname? Because its the same person or are they brothers/cousins or any other relatives, or coincidence?

Picture is from DC Comics, but unsure which one in particular.

Comment: Check out  [Earth 7642](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-7642), a part of the Marvel Multiverse that is an earth where Marvel and DC Characters both exist. Not quite the same as the main Marvel Universe (Earth-616) connecting with the main DC Universe, but might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The barriers between universes are traversable, but are protected by the most powerful force in either continuity: _[The Legal Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright)_.

Comment: There are other Marvel/DC crossovers- I've read two Batman/ Punisher books and both implied their respective hometowns were in the same universe.

Comment: Check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercompany_crossover) for a number of crossover events.

Comment: "[Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_(name))" is a common surname that anyone can have.  I knew a Professor Wilson in college; does this mean that Deadpool is real?

Comment: I have no idea why you would assume that two characters with the same surname in entirely different franchises must be related, or are the same person.

Comment: Don't forget about DC and IDW crossovers! ;) https://www.dccomics.com/reader/#/comics/376786

Comment: There was also a Batman/Hulk crossover but it was pretty bad.  The second Superman/Spiderman comic also featured Hulk and Wonder Woman along with a plethora of characters from both companies.

Comment: @jwodder that has nothing to do with this. They are working in the same genre so i was just wondering

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR Summary:

Yes, there have been some DC/Marvel crossovers that have taken place in an alternate universe where the characters share a single world; however, there have also been some that have not - including the one your image references.

---

As other answers have noted, there are a number of Marvel/DC crossovers where the characters appear to reside on the same Earth, starting with the Superman/Spider-Man "treasury" edition sized comic published in the mid-1970s.

Marvel and DC crossed over several more times in the late 1970s and early 1980s with the same assumptions (everyone on the same Earth): another Spider-Man/Superman story; Batman/Hulk; and X-Men/New Teen Titans.

These original 4 crossovers seem to be highly negotiated; they feature characters of comparable importance for both companies, both as the protagonists and the antagonists (first Supes/Spidey had Doctor Octopus and Luthor as the villains; X-Men/Titans has Darkseid and Dark Phoenix), where the story seemed to come from the characters that were negotiated, rather than the story idea coming first and the characters coming after (note that the Titans hadn't had anything to do with Darkseid, as I recall; Trigon would have made more sense). I'm not necessarily saying that's true - but, these certainly had that *feel*.

A fifth such story was planned for the mid 1980s (JLA/Avengers), but the negotiations came to an impasse, and it never materialized. DC/Marvel crossovers stopped for several years, at that point.

In the 1990s, as Dark Horse and Image became significant players in the marketplace, inter-company crossovers became more prevalent (not common, but not something with the earth-shaking significance with which fandom greeted the first Spidey/Superman crossover, or the X-Men/Titans one).

DC and Marvel did several crossovers during this time (Batman seemed to be the most likely participant from the DC side - I seem to recall crossovers with him and Captain America, and with him and the Punisher). However, the stories began to feel more natural, and less like a legal negotiation. I think even then most (but not necessarily all) of these stories involved the characters simply existing on the same Earth, rather than having to travel to some other dimension to meet.

In the late 1990s, Marvel and DC had a company-wide crossover: *DC vs. Marvel*/*Marvel vs. DC*. It was a 4 issue mini-series, and the order of the company names depended on which company published each issue. In this series, the characters did *not* live on a single Earth - the DC and Marvel Universes were apparently those actually published at that point, and the character were brought together to fight each other, some from the DCU to the Marvel U, some the other direction.

Aside: at one point the universes were merged, and both DC and Marvel published a week's worth of comics from the merged universe (the Amalgam Universe), with characters and groups that were a deliberate mash-up (Super-Soldier (Captain America/Superman), Iron Lantern (Iron Man/Green Lantern), JLX (Justice League/X-Men), etc). This was well-received enough that the companies did it again for one week about a year later, mostly with different titles and featured characters.

And, a few years later, in issues cover-dated September 2003 through March 2004, there was the four-issue *JLA/Avengers* / *Avengers/JLA* (again, the order depending on which company published which issues). This was not a resurrection of the 1980s proposed project; but, was a replacement of sorts for it. As I recall, multiple well-placed people in both companies remembered the abandoned project, and the disappointment when it fell into Limbo. The then-current writer of the Avengers, Kurt Busiek, had also worked for DC, and had at least worked with the JLA characters (he wrote a *Red Tornado* mini-series in the 1980s), and he was picked to write the crossover.

As noted elsewhere, this is where the image in the question comes from.

---

By the 1970s, both DC and Marvel had established multiple alternate universes of some sort. DC had Earth-1, Earth-2, Earth-3, Earth-S, Earth-X, etc.; Marvel had an alternate universe where Reed Richards had become the Thing, and, in 1975, started publishing *What If*, featuring stories of universes where some facet of Marvel history was different (Spider-Man joined the Fantastic Four; Wolverine became a vampire; etc.). Characters from different alternate worlds met on a regular basis in DC's comics; it was much rarer for this to happen at Marvel, but we did get a glimpse of a brand-new alternate universe on a monthly basis.

However, for legal reasons, interactions between characters from different *companies* was much rarer. While (technically) both the Marvel and DC multiverses include/included a world with both DC and Marvel characters on it, only stories published jointly by both companies would every see that world. In practical terms, the DC multiverse consisted of universes where all the characters are owned by DC, or in the public domain, and the Marvel multiverse consists of universes where all the characters are public domain, or owned by Marvel. At some point, the term *omniverse* was created to deal with this reality. A *multiverse* was seen as all the universes that could regularly interact, belonging to a particular company; whereas the *omniverse* consisted of all possible multiverses: DC, Marvel, Disney; Tarzan, Lord of the Rings, Sherlock Holmes; Indiana Jones, Alien, Predator; Star Trek, Buffy, Farscape; and so many more.

So, you can think of DC and Marvel as being (essentially) independent multiverses, that are part of the single *omniverse*. And, think that it's easier to moved around and visit within your own multiverse; it takes more than one set of the "Powers That Be" to journey out of your multiverse to another one.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shared universe, called Earth-7642 by Marvel, and Crossover-Earth by DC, in which characters from both Marvel and DC (along with other franchises) all interact.

From the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-7642):

> This world was formally listed as Crossover-Earth in the ICG Crisis on Infinite Earths Official Index and The Official Crisis on Infinite Earths Crossover Index both of which became sources for the second volume of the Crisis on Infinite Earths: Absolute Edition making them completely canonal to DC's Pre-Crisis multiverse.

While I haven't found anything stating that it's canonically part of the Marvel Multiverse, it has an identifying number, so I would assume that it is. So, at least Pre-Crisis, it would theoretically have been possible for an entity to travel from the main Marvel universe (Earth-616) to Earth-7642, and then from there to any of the Pre-Crisis DC universes.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is from the 2003-2004 crossover series JLA/Avengers, Avengers/JLA.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLA/Avengers

The two superhero teams are chosen by 2 powerful beings Krona and The Gamesmaster as champions in a contest between them and are manipulated into fighting to gain control of various powerful artifacts in order to win the contest. The teams are told that their universes will be destroyed unless they are victorious.